# How can I add file upload option in my rasa chatbot?

Tags: javascript, python, html, rasa

I am trying to make a chatbot for technical support and I want to add an option for the user to upload a screenshot of the issue, I am using Botfront for the frontend. Is there any way this can be implemented into my chatbot ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on rasa forum. Using Google I found [How to upload files like (pdf, docx)? - Rasa Open Source - Rasa Community Forum](https://forum.rasa.com/t/how-to-upload-files-like-pdf-docx/29568). But maybe you find more posts.